# How to selecting the first row for each different ID in a table with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table like the one below and I want to select the first of the repeating items according to the ID value in this table.

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>07.12.2020</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Robert A. Crane</td>
      <td>Repair</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>07.12.2020</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Robert A. Crane</td>
      <td>Repair</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>07.12.2020</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
      <td>Repair</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>07.12.2020</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
      <td>Repair</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>07.12.2020</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
      <td>Repair</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

As a result, the first row with an ID value of 5 and the first row with an ID of 22 should be selected.

**It should look like this:**

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr style="background:yellow">
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Robert A. Crane</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Robert A. Crane</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="background:yellow">
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

NOTE: Some people give negative points without answering this question or writing a link to the solution to the problem. If you answer the question instead of minus points, it will be more appreciated.

Comment: My friend who gave negative points to the question, I couldn't find the answer to this question in stackoverflow. It would be more appreciated if you answer the question instead of giving a negative score!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question:

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("table > tbody").children('tr:first').css("background-color", "#ffff00");
  
    var column_id = $("table > tbody").children('tr:first').find('td').eq(1).text();
    $('table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
      if (column_id != $(this).find('td').eq(1).text()) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffff00");
        column_id = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Robert A. Crane</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Robert A. Crane</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>07.12.2020</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>Loretta Acosta</td>
          <td>Repair</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

  </body>
</html>
```